# Pdf files without layer

Tags: ios, pdf, host

Well,it is not really a programming question.

I have to host some pdf files and view them online from a mobile device.I know that already there are lots of sites like that (like google docs) ,but i do not want users see the gray layer of google docs.They should see only the pdf file.

What google docs does :

[image]

What the hosting site should do :

[image]

So do you know a free site like this , to host my pdf files? Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys! I found it !

For everyone interested, i downloaded "cloudapp" from app store!

Works like a charm :)

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: Wasn't it a complete answer?